# Create MySQL database from schema in one go

Tags: mysql, schema

I have a sql schema dump from phpmyadmin. I want to create a new database from that schema on a new machine. I have tried this:

```
mysql -uuser -ppwd < schema.sql
```

It says no database is selected. I know that I could `CREATE database` first then import, but is there an easier way to do this? I plan to do it in a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can even embed `CREATE DATABASE` statement in your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -uuser -ppwd name_of_data_base < schema.sql
```

Comment: I got this error: ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'name_of_data_base'

Comment: You do have to put the name of the DB you want to use in that place. Since you didn't say what your db's name is, I put in "name_of_db" as a placeholder.

Comment: but the problem is I want to create a new DB and import schema at the same time. There is no DB in MySQL when I import.